# Set Date/Time to 00:00:00

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an array of dates with different times in the date.

Example: {4/15/13 05:00:00, 03/10/13 13:00:00, 02/10/13 02:00:00, etc.}

If I wanted to change just the hour to 00:00:00 so the array would read:

{4/15/13 00:00:00, 03/10/13 00:00:00, 02/10/13 00:00:00, etc.}

How would I do that?

I've tried using getTime(), but I don't have control over just the hours. Any help would be great.
Thanks!

EDIT: I tried this loop:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < gValues.length; i++) { // repeat loop
    sheet.getRange(i + 2, 7, 1, 1).setValue(gValues[i][0].setHours(00,00,00,00));
  }
```

But instead of the desired result, I get this value: "12/20/5828963 0:00:00" for every single cell.

Comment: are the values in your sheet dates or strings ? (ie can you change the date format in the spreadsheet format settings) what was the actual value that returned "12/20/5828963 0:00:00"

Comment: No they are dates, not strings.
{3/16/2013 17:00:00
3/16/2013 17:00:00
3/20/2013 5:00:00
3/20/2013 5:00:00
3/21/2013 5:00:00
3/21/2013 5:00:00
3/21/2013 5:00:00
3/25/2013 5:00:00
3/25/2013 5:00:00
3/13/2013 5:00:00
3/26/2013 1:00:01
3/6/2013 4:00:00
3/5/2013 4:00:00
3/19/2013 5:00:00
3/26/2013 1:00:00
3/2/2013 4:00:00
3/18/2013 5:00:00}

Comment: I don't see any separators in your example... ?? see edited answer with an example.

Comment: They're in different cells, so they are separated. I just copy/pasted the cells over.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Google Apps Script is JavaScript, date manipulations [are explained here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp),

setting the hours goes like this :

```
Date.setHours(hour,min,sec,millisec)
```

here is an example :

```
//   3/16/2013 17:00:00

function test(){
 var x = new Date('3/16/2013 17:00:00');// x is now a date object
 x.setHours(0,0,0,0); set  hours to 0, min Secs and milliSecs as well
 Logger.log(x);// show result
}
```

Logger value : `Sat Mar 16 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2013`

Comment: Your example did it. Thanks! For some reason I have to make new Date() a separate variable.

Comment: @user1786546 - of course you have to put it in a separate variable, because the "setHours" function returns a number and if you assign the "new Date" AND "setHours" together, then the "x" variable will get this number and not the date object, as wanted.

Answer (score -1):

When your system time is configured to use UTC:

```
DateUtils.setSeconds(DateUtils.setMinutes(DateUtils.setHours(new Date(),5),30),0)
```

Otherwise:

```
DateUtils.setSeconds(DateUtils.setMinutes(DateUtils.setHours(new Date(),0),0),0)
```

Comment: please explain or write the result of the action or th esttes you suggest, for us to understand if it answer the question or not