# Having trouble working with dates in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working with a number of dates in Google Sheets, but it seems to always enter the date as a string.

`sheet.getRange(3,11,sheet.getLastRow()-3, 1).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "UTC-5", "dd/MM/yyyy"));`

is how I enter the date, but when I test it with

`Logger.log(typeof extractedDate);` it tells me that its a string.

If I'm working with hundreds of dates, it seems to me that it would be a huge waste of time/resources to have to parse each date as a string each time and convert it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
sheet.getRange(3,11,sheet.getLastRow()-3, 1).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "UTC-5", "dd/MM/yyyy"));
```

use

```
sheet.getRange(3,11,sheet.getLastRow()-3, 1).setValue(new Date());
```

The above will pase the current date and time to the spreadsheet which will be displayed accordingly to the cell formatting.

If you want to pass the date without the time, instad of `new Date()` use

```
new Date(new Date().getFullYear(),new Date().getMonth() , new Date().getDate())
```

---

Better alternative

```
var now = new Date();
var today = now.setHours(0,0,0,0);
sheet.getRange(3,11,sheet.getLastRow()-3, 1).setValue(today);
```

Related

- [Set Date/Time to 00:00:00](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15231222/1595451)
- [How to get current date without time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25445377/1595451)
- [Javascript date method without time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26528085/1595451)
- [Script inserted today's date into spreadsheet is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54985339/1595451)
- [create button to add new line with today date and blank other fields](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55772482/1595451)

Comment: "*If you want to pass the date without the time…*" it's less code (and more efficient) to do `new Date(new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0))`.  ;-)

Comment: thank you @Rubén
But now it only shows as this very long number.  How do I address that?
And what time zone is it set for?

Comment: @Rubén—nor does more. The less code creates 2 dates and calls 1 method vs 4 dates and 3 methods for the longer code, so a lot more efficient (as well as being a lot less to type/send/parse/etc.). ;-)

Comment: @TzviL—date objects don't have a timezone, they're always created as UTC. The date created in the above answer will be for the current date at 00:00:00 in the timezone of the host system, so might be a different date UTC. As long as you use local methods (i.e. those without UTC or ISO in the name), you'll get values for the host system timezone.